# Is there a "correct" way of using piping with load()?

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

It seems the pipe operator creates a temporary environment that then discards the loaded data:

```
library(magrittr)
"thing.rdata" -> thing
# Nothing happens:
thing %>% load
# Works as expected:
thing %>% load(envir=globalenv())
```

I'm not sure if using `globalenv()` is the best way to solve this issue as I was hoping to keep something simple like `load(thing)` (which does work).

Comment: Why do you need to pipe this?  `load(thing)` seems practical.

Comment: In practice the filepath is the output of a series of piped functions, so I'd like to avoid the unreadability caused by having to nest all of the previous steps inside `load()`.

Comment: You don't have to nest all the previous steps, you just assign int to a variable, `thing`, and then do `load(thing)`.

Comment: Sure, but then I'll have a `thing` lying around that I have no further use for. I know it's no big deal but none of this really is, I just want the code to be as neat as possible.

Comment: `loadglob <- function(x) load(x, envir=globalenv())` then replace `load` with `loadglob` ?

Comment: Agree that would during interactive workflow, but as I mentioned in the initial post, I don't suppose that using `envir=globalenv()` is recommended practice. It seems `envir=parent.env(environment())` also works and should be more robust, but it'd still be nice to get confirmation that this is indeed a sane thing to do in general.

Comment: You could use `parent.frame()`, it's the same as `parent.env(environment())` as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

A kind reddit user provided me a link that had the answer.

I'll quote the relevant section:

> The use of assign with the pipe does not work because it assigns it to
>   a temporary environment used by %>%. If you do want to use assign with
>   the pipe, you must be explicit about the environment:
>
> ```
> env <- environment()
> "x" %>% assign(100, envir = env)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Other functions with this problem include `get()` and `load()`.

Source: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer you got from a different source. But does it really answer your question? How do you integrate this into your pipeline? Creating an environment beforehand to load into (and then, presumably, attaching the environment?) seems like an even more round-about solution  than what I proposed in comments and you didn't like - assigning the path to `thing` and then using `load(thing)`. Maybe there's a clever use of  `parent.frame()` (with maybe `n = 2`?) that gives your desired result?

Comment: If I understand the usage of `environment()`, it's merely making sure that it loads the data in the same context it's being called from, as opposed to `globalenv()`, which has a larger scope than would generally be needed. I feel that the answer given there is adequate for my question in the sense that it specifically addresses how to make things work properly when one insists in using a pipe. Now that I see what that entails, though, your solution certainly seems preferable.

Comment: I suppose the true SO way to go about this would be to benchmark both approaches and see if there are any meaningful differences between them. I'll gladly grant you the answer for this question if you do that, otherwise I'll try to add it here later.

Comment: Benchmarking this will be pointless - there won't be any substantial difference and it's *extremely* difficult to imagine a workflow where this is a bottleneck. And if performance was that critical you wouldn't be using pipes anyway to save on the minor cost of `%>%`.

Comment: Rather, I would say this does a good job explaining the *why* of the problem, but doesn't directly answer the question. Your question seemed to ask for a way to pipe a file name into `load` and have the object loaded into the current environment, without a "detour" of assigning another object. And I don't see from this answer how (if) that is possible.